# Left-align name/rep for users with no avatar

Tags: feature-request, design, user-card

The recent change in the signup screens has led to a significant influx of users with no avatar (citation needed).  These folks' lack of avatar leads to an odd appearance due to the site reserving the space for the avatar, so it looks like their names and rep are aligned oddly.

Can we remove that reservation or 'blank' avatar, and simply left align their name/rep?

[image]

Alternately, can we add a default image for avatarless users, and require its use (I don't mind if someone decides to upload a clear gif, but for anyone not intentionally messing with things, require something or the placeholder)?  See Nicael's answer below for example.

Comment: That user *does* have an avatar. Are you accessing the site from behind a firewall that blocks certain social networks?

Comment: Nope.  Just regular Comcast.

Comment: Do a hard refresh of the page - it could just be that your browser hasn't loaded the image yet.

Comment: What about me? Do you see my avatar?

Comment: @nicael - where? Here or on SO?

Comment: I did a hard refresh, still don't see it.  I do see the image for both of the recent users that made me think of posting this when I go to source, and can load it there - but don't see it here!

Comment: @Chris I was going to ask Joe, if he can see my avatar there.

Comment: Yes, I see your avatar here fine (or at SO, also fine.)

Comment: So this isn't about truly nonextant avatars, this is about avatars that don't load properly.  How hard is that to change using SO's standard tools I wonder (detecting a non-loaded avatar and replacing with a default one)?

Answer (score 1):

I do not support this idea because I get used to the current location of all parts of user card. So moving user name and rep to the left if there this user has no avatar will look a bit unusual and breaks the design:

> [image]

I get used to this user card architecture:

[image]

What I can suggest is to add anonymous avatar if a user has no avatar:
[image]

Comment: I would support this as well - anything to get rid of that annoying empty space!